# save and load data

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults

in my game i use NSUserDefults to save the user highscore. in the first time i finushed the game my highscore is set to the game score, but every time after that the score in the game is automatically set as the highscore. the weirdness here is that id my game score is 0 then my highscore is stay as the biggest score, but if in the end of some game my score is 100 is sets as highscore but a game after that if my score is 50 my highscore is sets as 50(although the score was lower then my highscore).
here is my viewdidload code:

```
    highScore = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"HighScore"] intValue ];
highScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",highScore];
```

here is my checkIfHighscore code:

```
-(void)checkIfHighScore
{
    if(gameOverScore > highScore)
    {
        highScore = gameOverScore;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:highScore] forKey:@"HighScore"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    }
    highScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", highScore];
}
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your highScore loaded form `NSUserDefaults` is going to be an `Object` of type `id`, you should cast it to `NSNumber`, secondly in your `checkIfHighScore` method, you should compare `highScore.intValue` to `gameOverScore`, and then:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:gameOverScore] forKey:@"HighScore"];
```

Notice how you are mixing number objects and scalar types (`int`), you can't use the `<` and `>` operators, or even `==` between an `Object` and a scalar variable.

Comment: but my highscore is already an int type, so i cant use highscore.intValue

Comment: another thing, when i tried to cast my highScore to NSNumber like this:     highScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:highScore] forKey:@"HighScore"]; i get this error message: "Assigning to 'int' from incomparable type 'void'"

Comment: Maybe you could put your class on a gist and share the link, it's true I didn't see you was using as an int. I would like to help but I will need more code.

Comment: why do you need more code? all the code that refers to the NSUserDefults and to my highscore label is here.

Comment: after i look again in my code i think that the problem is un this line of code: if(gameOverScore > highScore) in the checkIfHighscore function.

Comment: Well the reason is maybe the flow of loading from the user defaults is not occurring at the right time. Just NSLog before the if statement each value, or better, use a breakpoint to inspect the values. I suspect that highScore is always 0 at this stage which is why the game's score is always being saved as the high score